# ASP.NET MVC application failing with a null exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

Currently failing when clicking into the `AddApplication` web method with the following:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UniversityId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddApplication(System.String, Int32, System.String)' in 'NAA.Controllers.ApplicationController'.

I'll provide my DAO code, service and the code in the controller

DAO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NAA.Data;
using NAA.Data.IDAO;
using NAA.Data.DAO;
using NAA.Data.Repository;
using NAA.Data.Models.Domain;

namespace NAA.Data.DAO
{
    public class ApplicationDAO : IApplicationDAO
    {
        //ADDAPPLICATION METHOD NEEDED HERE(Refer to Addmusic tutorial for tips)
        public void AddUniversityToCollection(Application application, University university, NAAContext context)
        {
            context.Universities.Find(university.UniversityId).Applications.Add(application);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddApplication(Application application, NAAContext context)
        {
            context.Applications.Add(application); //this adds applications what's stored in application and pulls to interface
            //context.SaveChanges(); // this saves changes to the database
        }
    }
}
```

The service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NAA.Data.Repository;
using NAA.Data.DAO;
using NAA.Data.IDAO;
using NAA.Data.Models;
using NAA.Data.Models.Domain;
using NAA.services.IService;

namespace NAA.services.Service
{
    public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
    {
        private IApplicationDAO applicationDAO;
        private IUniversityDAO universityDAO;
        private IUserDAO userDAO;

        public ApplicationService()
        {
            applicationDAO = new ApplicationDAO();
            universityDAO = new UniversityDAO();
            userDAO = new UserDAO();
        }

        public void AddApplication(NAA.services.Models.UniversityApplication application, string UserId)
        {
            Application newApplication = new Application()
            {
                Course = application.Course,
                Statement = application.Statement,
                TeacherContact = application.TeacherContact
            };

            using (var context = new NAAContext())
            {
                applicationDAO.AddApplication(newApplication, context);
                User user = userDAO.GetUser(application.UserId, context);
                userDAO.AddUniversityToCollection(newApplication, user, context);
                University university = universityDAO.GetUniversity(application.UniversityId, context);
                universityDAO.AddUniversityToCollection(newApplication, university, context);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
using NAA.Data.Models.Domain;
using NAA.OutService;
using NAA.services.Models;
using NAA.services.Service;
using NAA.Data.DAO;
using NAA.Data.Repository;
using NAA.Data.IDAO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NAA.services.IService;

namespace NAA.Controllers
{
    public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        IApplicationService applicationService;

        public ApplicationController()
        {
            applicationService = new ApplicationService();
        }

        // GET: Application
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddApplication(string UserId, int UniversityId, string Course)
        {
            ViewBag.UserId = UserId;
            ViewBag.UniversityId = UniversityId;
            ViewBag.Name = Course;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddApplication(UniversityApplication application, string UserID)
        {
            applicationService.AddApplication(application, UserID);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUniversities", "User", new { id = application.UserId });
        }

        //public ActionResult GetUniversities(int profileId)
        //{
        //    ViewBag.profileId = profileId;
        //}
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to explain where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:
Included here is the code that calls the AddApplication web method:

```
@model IEnumerable<NAAInServices.ProxyToSHUWebService.SHUCourse>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetSHUCourses";
}

<h2>GetSHUCourses</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CRequirements)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CDescription)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CDegree)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CTarif)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CNSS)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CRequirements)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CDegree)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CTarif)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNSS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Apply", "AddApplication", new { UserId = ViewBag.UserID, UniversityId = ViewBag.UniversityId, Course = ViewBag.Course, Controller = "Application" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Could you share your call to the AddApplication controller action? Probably you are missing the UniversityId. You can try changing the UniversityId in the controller from int to  int? to see if you can get more information on whether or not you are setting the UniversityId correctly

Comment: Try to put breakpoint inside GET AddApplication and check input parameters. Also just for test you could change your type from int to string and check the parameters. It would be great if you share your call url with us.

Comment: Hi I've edited the original post with code that includes the call to the AddApplication action. Thanks a lot!